# How do you set the value of a cell to 1:00PM instead of 13:00:00 using java script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, automation

I am trying to make a script to automate a google form registration that links to a google calendar. So a user will submit a response with all the details about their visit, such as what school is visiting, number of students, etc... and once they submit the form, the script will run.

The following information is added to the sheet by the script:

- Start time
- End time
- Combination of start date and time
- Combination of end date and time

The start time and end time to the visit is are constant:

- Start time: 8:00AM
- End time: 1:00PM.

So far my code can set the start value at 8:00AM and the end time to 1:00PM. When I add the start date and start time into one cell, it will display the date and 8:00AM. When I add the end date and time, it'll show the date, but it'll show 1:00PM as, 13:00:00.

[image: Screenshot of google sheet being used]

Here is the code I have been using temporarily:

```
function insertTime() {
  // get spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');

  sheet.getRange('$K2:K').setValue("8:00:00"); //Sets start time of the event to 8AM
  sheet.getRange('$L2:L').setValue("13:00:00"); //Sets the end time of the event to 1PM
  sheet.getRange('$M2:M').setValue("=Sum($G2+$K2)"); //Combines the start date and time into one cell
  sheet.getRange('$N2:N').setValue("=Sum($G2+$L2)");//Combines the end date and time into one cell
}
```

How do you set the value of a cell to 1:00PM instead of 13:00:00 using javascript when you add the date and time together?

Answer (score 0):

See [`setNumberFormat(numberFormat)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat) and [Date and Number Formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats) to programmatically set the format for a cell/range.